# How can i get inspect.getsource to respond to changes in source code?

Tags: python, inspection

I make two files:

```
#test_func.py
def test():
    print('hello')
```

and

```
#test_inspect.py
import inspect
import test_func

reload(inspect)
reload(test_func)
reload(inspect)
reload(test_func)

print inspect.getsource(test_func.test)
```

Running `import test_inspect` from IPython or other interactive shell prints the right thing:

```
def test():
    print('hello')
```

but if I edit and save test_func.py to be:

```
#test_func.py
def test():
    print('good bye')
```

I still get:

```
def test():
    print('hello')
```

when I run `reload(test_inspect)` from the shell.  How can I convince the `inspect` module to re-read the source file?

(If you *must* know why I want to do this, I will elaborate in the comments, but for right now, I'd like to simply know if there is a workaround for this or if there is something fundamental about the inspect module that prevents this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import linecache
linecache.clearcache()
```

Comment: Ahh. Much better.  Thank you.

Comment: I think this is actually a bug in `linecache` or `inspect` which should be fixed in python 3.5. Thanks for the workaround. See https://bugs.python.org/issue1218234